# HTML / CSS: Text within my div is not lining up?

Tags: html, css

Code: http://pastebin.com/mtLHtjar

I do not understand why the text in my **navigation** `div` is not lined up.

I have **navigationLeft** `div` and **navigationRight** `div` within **navigation**.

The text in **navigationLeft** is above the text in **navigationRight** for a reason I am unaware of. Could someone point out my mistake?

Comment: Thats because they are in different `ul` s

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the little tick there. In my opinion it's not very intuitive. Thanks for the help by the way, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In action (see in Full screen)

There are so many solutions to this like:

- Float (current solution)
- Inline-block
- Flex
- Table-cell

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#navigation{
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #292526;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

#navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#navigation a {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigationLeft {
  float: left;
  font-size: 180%;
}

#navigationRight {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation">
     <div id="navigationLeft">
        <a href="#">Vist Clare Ireland</a>
     </div>
     <ul id="navigationRight">    
        <li><a href="#">Home |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bars |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurants |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Map |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>        
</div>
```

You may search them for further readings.

## UPDATE

This is update to fulfill the last comment from question's author:

You should use `display: inline-block` for that purpose

```css
#navigation{
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #292526;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
#navigationLeft {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 180%;
}

#navigationRight {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#navigation ul{
  float: right;
}
#navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#navigation a {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div id="navigationLeft">
     <a href="#">Vist Clare Ireland</a>
  </div><div id="navigationRight">
    <ul>    
      <li><a href="#">Home |</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News |</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact |</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About |</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE 2

for the `inline-block` to work as expected, you need to remove the extra space between two elements. If you add a white-space like

- space
- tab
- newine ( **This is your case** )

between them, a gap will appear.

Depending on the situation, you can use either of the following methods to get rid of the gap:

1- Put theme in one line

```
    <input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text">
```

2- Removing the space ( Don't worry, it is correct! :) )

```
    <input type="text"><
    input type="text"><
    input type="text">
```

3- Use HTML comments

```
    <input type="text"><!--
    --><input type="text">
```

I suggest you to use the **Number 1** method (Put theme in one line), but either will work.

Comment: I see how the two sets of text begin on the same line. How would I go about making the text on the right be in the centre of the text on the left rather than them being exactly on the same line.

Comment: Check my UPDATE answer in a minute.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help by the way, thank you so much <3 </div><div id="navigationRight"> - If you move <div id="navigationRight"> to a new line it once again "breaks" it. I wish to put it on a new line simply for the actual layout of my code, is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/D1fKeZGP - Broken | http://pastebin.com/BQnC8Phz - Working and the only difference is spacing.

Comment: I have spent some time attempting to place all I have done so far all on one page. I wish for there to be no scrollbars, I do not want to make the scrollbars invisible or so forth, I mean have the web page fit on one page of the browser without the user having the need to scroll for aesthetic purposes.

I have played around with the width and height of divs along with a number of other things in an attempt to achieve my desired result but with no success unfortunately. What would I be required to change regarding my code in order to achieve this? http://pastebin.com/xnpz2HLh

Comment: Always try to propose ur problems regardin the title of question page. Does that realy matter with Text within my div is not lining up? If not search or post new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Visit Clare</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    #navigation {
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #292526;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }


    #navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
        font-size: 120%;
        color: white;           
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
        font-size: 120%;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navigationLeft {
        font-size: 180%;
        display:inline-block
    }

    #navigationRight {
         float:right;
         width:300px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="navigationLeft">
            <li><a href="#">Visit Clare Ireland</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="navigationRight">    
            <li><a href="#">Home |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bars |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Restaurants |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Map |</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>        
</div>
</body>

</html>
```